# Keep a computed ranking updated in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here i have a requirement like biddin db structor is like

```
Id   Name       Amount    Bidding_Level
1     Apple      50         L3
2     Mac        30        L2
3     Nokia      10        L1
```

Here my Requirement is whenever user Enter amount   **Bidding_Level**  Comes dynamic
Like if any user enter Amount as 5  He will Become `L1 
And all other Like  as  Nokia L2 Mac L3 Apple L4`

Comment: It seems like bidding level can be *computed* from the Amount column. As such, you probably shouldn't *store* this value, but compute it on demand. Storing computed data just  *introduces* the possibility of the stored values being inconsistent with the base data.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes based on Amount Bidding Level should generated as per amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as Damien suggested, it seems that this value shouldn't be stored but computed when needed. When you have computed columns (that don't automatically update) then you are begging for **additional maintenance tasks** (what happens if someone changes the product name but keeps the same ID? and when someone deletes a bid?) and **pointless processing** (you might calculate the bid level and recieve another bid before actually needing the current bid level).

That being said, you can reset the bid ranking with a trigger, which will have to be after inserts, updates or deletes (you don't explain your business logic much).

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_SetBiddingLevel ON Bids AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    -- If the amount was updated, a new row was added or a row was deleted
    IF UPDATE(Amount) OR (
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted) AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))
    BEGIN

        ;WITH NewBidLevels AS
        (
            SELECT
                B.Id,
                NewBidLevel = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.Amount ASC)
            FROM
                Bids AS B
        )
        UPDATE B SET
            Bidding_Level = 'L' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), N.NewBidLevel)
        FROM
            Bids AS B
            INNER JOIN NewBidLevels AS N ON B.Id = N.Id

    END

END
```

Please note that the tigger will consider *all records of the table*, since it has to update all records for each change on any amount (which is very bad for performance). You should calculate this ranking each time it's needed instead.